# pandas read_csv doesn't parse comma decimal separator when using dtype?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis

I want to open a csv file using comma as the decimal separator. I pass the `decimal=","`. However, I always get the error that the float value of the last line of the csv file is not parsed successfully (I tried deleting some lines of the csv file, and the error always occurs on the last line...).
The float value is also quoted in the csv, so I pass `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`.

Anyone knowing what happens here? If I remove the `dtype` option it works, but the column `amount` is a string...

Here's the code I use (reformatted for readability):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y')
expenses = pd.read_csv("/home/jovyan/work/expenses.csv",
 quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, decimal=",", header=None, na_values=[""],
 names=['date','category','amount','currency','note','tags'],
 parse_dates=["date"], date_parser=dateparse,  
 dtype={"date": str,"category": str, "amount":float, "currency": str,
 "note": str, "tags": str})
```

Comment: Hard answering this question without data sample - the best share file sample via gdocs, dropbox or similar. Is it possible?

Comment: Or just examining the last line locally and seeing what data is actually there

Answer (score 2):

I thought it was a problem of a pandas behaviour I didn't understand, but it appears that the problem was in the data read. The float column was also using a thousands separator, eg '1.345,50'. Those lines caused the trouble. The solution was to use the read_csv option `thousands='.'`.

The error message is confusing though, as the value reported as not convertible to float is taken from the last line in the csv file, not from the line causing the trouble....

As reference, here is the error message:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-e77d6530ab30> in <module>()
      3 import csv
      4 dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y')
----> 5 expenses = pd.read_csv("/home/jovyan/work/test.csv", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, decimal=",", header=None, na_values=[""],names=['date','category','amount','currency','note','tags'],parse_dates=["date"], date_parser=dateparse,  dtype={"date": str,"category": str, "amount":float, "currency": str, "note": str, "tags": str})
      6 expenses['tags']=expenses['tags'].str.split(",")
      7 #,  dtype={"date": str,"category": str, "amount":float, "currency": str, "note": str, "tags": str}

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, doublequote, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    676                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    677 
--> 678         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    679 
    680     parser_f.__name__ = name

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    444 
    445     try:
--> 446         data = parser.read(nrows)
    447     finally:
    448         parser.close()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1034                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
   1035 
-> 1036         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1037 
   1038         # May alter columns / col_dict

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1846     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1847         try:
-> 1848             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1849         except StopIteration:
   1850             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0,99'
```